# What is the purpose of this.props.onChange()?

Tags: reactjs

From the react quickstart: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

The purpose of the line:

```
  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
  }
```

was never explained and I can't figure out what it *does*. Is onChange a built in method of props? I thought props was simply just parameters for components, why can it invoke functions?

Comment: *"why can it invoke functions"*. Prop can be a function.

Comment: In this case component might be used something like `<Component onChange={value => alert(value)}>`.

Answer (score 8):

I came here with the same question, but I understand it now (at least I think I do). The issue is that `onChange` in the `Calculator` class is a prop, but in the render portion of the class `TemperatureInput`, it's an event listener. Sometimes I see this in React, where the same name is used on two completely different things, and I find it can easily create confusion. Here's what happens in the following code block:

```jsx
class TemperatureInput extends React.Component {
  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onChange(e.target.value); **(2)**
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <input value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} /> **(3)**
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}

class Calculator extends React.Component {
  handleCelsiusChange(value) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TemperatureInput
          scale="c"
          value={celsius}
          onChange={this.handleCelsiusChange} /> **(1)**
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

1. In `Calculator`, a made up prop called `onChange` passes a reference to the method `handleCelsiusChange` to `TemperatureInput`
2. `this.props.onChange()` in `TemperatureInput` is now a reference to `handleCelsiusChange()` in `Calculator`
3. `onChange={this.handleChange}` is an event listener, which will fire `handleChange()` up on the change of the input field.

In conclusion, `onChange` as a prop is custom, `onChange` as an event listener is built in. The prop just passes a function reference from an ancestor to the child so you can run it in the child.

Comment: To clarify, changes to TemperatureInput's input field is now sent up to the parent ( Calculator )'s state?

Comment: Yep, this is React's way of sending up data to the parent component. In this case we're taking the input value and triggering `handleChange(e)` which in turn triggers `handleCelsiusChange(value)` in the parent.

Answer (score 7):

> I thought props was simply just parameters for components, why can it invoke functions?

You're right, but those parameters can also be callbacks/functions. E.g:

Definition:

```jsx
class Comp extends Component {
  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (<input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)) />
  }
}
```

Usage:

```jsx
<Comp onChange={(a) => console.log(a)} />
```

Answer (score 4):

Got a clue from SeattleFrey's answer, maybe the author of that code shouldn't name this parameter onchange. It is so confusing for a starter of ReactJs like me.

I name it myChange instead of onChange. It is actually a function passed in as a parameter. And e.target.value is the parameter for that function.Props can contain objects as well as functions, since functions are also objects in Javascript

```jsx
class TemperatureInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {

    this.props.myChange(e.target.value);

  }

  render() {
    const value = this.props.value;
    const scale = this.props.scale;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature in {scaleNames[scale]}:</legend>
        <input value={value}
               onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}

class Calculator extends React.Component {

  handleCelsiusChange(value) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', value});

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <TemperatureInput
          scale="c"
          value={celsius}
          myChange={this.handleCelsiusChange} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just missed this sentence:

> If several components need access to the same state, it is a sign that the state should be lifted up to their closest common ancestor instead. In our case, this is the `Calculator`.

Your quoted code is from component `TemperatureInput`:

```jsx
class TemperatureInput extends React.Component {
  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <input value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}
```

And `TemperatureInput` is a child component of `Calculator`, where `TemperatureInput.onChange` is assigned to `Calculator. handleCelsiusChange`

```jsx
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  handleCelsiusChange(value) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TemperatureInput
          scale="c"
          value={celsius}
          onChange={this.handleCelsiusChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I still have no clue what that line does