# React setting "checked" state on radio buttons

Tags: css, reactjs

Having issues with a uni assignment.  In this assignment, we have some data as answers for a problem.  I need to build up a form to allow an answer to be selected.  In this assignment, there will only be one answer.  So I thought could just use a radio button, styled to look like a button, to avoid having to code in logic for checking how many answers we should have and set that.

To do this, I created a new AnswerGroup component and pass in an array of answers.

This is the array (taken using a console.log to show the structure):

```
Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​0: Object { chosen: 0, text: "10 \\mbox{ kg.}", correct: false }
​1: Object { text: "62 \\frac{2}{9} \\mbox{ kg.}", chosen: 0, correct: true }
​2: Object { text: "None of the above", chosen: 0, correct: false }
​3: Object { text: "1\\frac{17}{28} \\mbox{ kg.}", chosen: 0, correct: false }
​4: Object { chosen: 0, correct: false, text: "1260 \\mbox{ kg.}" }
​length: 5
```

To clarify the data structure in this object:
**Chosen** is meant to be used at a later stage, where the number of times a user has picked this answer is recorded (it is held in cloudstore, so ultimately that info feeds back)
**text** the text which will appear on the button (it is mathjax format, so looks strange)
**correct** a boolean representing if this is the correct answer or not.

And my AnswerComponent looks like this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { MathComponent } from 'mathjax-react'
import '../styles/radioStyles.css'

function AnswerComponent(props) {
  let answers = props.answersarray; 

  const [value, setValue] = useState(false)

  function handleChange() {
    setValue(value);
    // alert(value)    
  }

  return (
    <div className="col-12">
      <h3 className="text-center">Answer</h3>
      <div className="p-3 mb-2 bg-light">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="answerGroup">
            {
            answers.map((answer, id) => {

              let formulaButton;
              let label = answer.text;
                      
              label.includes('kg') ? formulaButton = true : formulaButton= false;
                      
              return (
              <>
              <input type='radio'
                    //  className={isActive ? 'radBtn' : 'selectedAnswer'}
                    className={'radBtn'}
                    //  checked={value}
                    name='answer'
                    id={id}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={answer.correct}
              />
              <label for={id}>{formulaButton === true ? <MathComponent tex={answer.text} /> :answer.text}</label>
              </>            
              )
            })
            }
          </div>          
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm text-center">
          <button className='btn-primary mb-2 p-4'>CHECK MY ANSWER</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>     
  )
}

export default AnswerComponent;
```

I have styled with the following:

````
/* .answerGroup input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
} */

.answerGroup label {
  background-color: #95a5a6;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem #798d8f;
  text-shadow: 0 0.075rem #617374;
}

.answerGroup label:hover {
  background-color: #a3b1b2;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem #87999a;
}  

.selectedAnswer {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem #798d8f;
  text-shadow: 0 0.075rem #617374;
}```

Updated question:
When I click on an individual radio button, I would like the background colour to change (I had created the selectedAnser class in the CSS - and I know that it duplicates the answergroup label class except the background colour)

What I want is that when the buttons are created, if I click on a check answer button, that if the radio with "correct=true" is selected, then the user gets a "well done" (now at this point, that button is somewhere else, but I am refactoring this on the fly - so that button **Could** end up in the react with the answer group - in fact, it is probably a good place for it.
````

Comment: As I can see you have multiple answers but I only one state for value. Is this desired?

Comment: Setting display: none means that those input elements aren't rendered so aren't clickable. I haven't looked closely at the rest of your code so don't know exactly what would work, but try opacity: 0 perhaps?

Comment: @AHaworth - thanks - that was a mistake on my part

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann - I was surprised when only one state was needed, at least it seemed to work (though that may fail on the next part where I try to use the selected item)

Answer (score 1):

As [@a-haworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10867454/a-haworth) correctly pointed out the culprit is this block of code.

```css
.answerGroup input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

I believe you added this to get the mathjax render/styled correctly but it straight up hides the radio buttons. So you can comment this block in your css file.

I wasn't able to render the equations so I changed `<label>` to `<button>` (changed the css accordingly). This renders the equations inside of the button.

> Note: You still have to click on the radio button instead of the grey button with equation; to select.

## Update

You are right to think about using this line.

```js
className={isActive ? 'radBtn' : 'selectedAnswer'}
```

But it should really be used as a prop for `<label>` instead of `<input>` since those radio buttons are just small blue circles whose color can't be changed. The bg-color you can change is the `<label>`. It would have been simple if label had some css selector like `checked` and would act like a radio button but I couldn't find any. So we are stuck with using react for changing the color (IMO this is the better way!)

There is still a remaining problem though. You can't get away with one `value = true/false` you need an array of `boolean` (or a number for the id of the option) to know which option is being selected. Then conditionally setting the class for `<label>` would get our job done.

## Code

```js
function AnswerGroup(props) {
  const answers = props.answersarray;
  // console.log('> ', answers);
  const [values, setValues] = useState(() =>
    answers.map((a) => false)
  );
  // console.log(values);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const option_id = Number(event.target.value);
    setValues(
      values.map((a, idx) => (option_id === idx ? true : false))
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className='col-12'>
      <h3 className='text-center'>Answer</h3>
      <div className='p-3 mb-2 bg-light'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='answerGroup'>
            {answers.map((answer, id) => {
              let formulaButton;
              let label = answer.text;

              label.includes('kg')
                ? (formulaButton = true)
                : (formulaButton = false);

              return (
                <React.Fragment key={id}>
                  <input
                    type='radio'
                    className={'radBtn'}
                    name='answer'
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={id}
                  />
                  <label
                    className={
                      values[id] ? 'selected' : 'notSelected'
                    }
                    forhtml={id}
                  >
                    {formulaButton === true ? (
                      <MathComponent tex={answer.text} />
                    ) : (
                      answer.text
                    )}
                  </label>
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='col-sm text-center'>
          <button className='btn-primary mb-2 p-4'>
            CHECK MY ANSWER
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
/* .answerGroup input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
} */

.notSelected {
  background-color: #95a5a6;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem #798d8f;
  text-shadow: 0 0.075rem #617374;
}

.answerGroup label:hover {
  background-color: #a3b1b2;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem #87999a;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #00ccff;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem #798d8f;
  text-shadow: 0 0.075rem #617374;
}
```

Comment: That was very stupid of me - commenting out the display none lets me see the radio - opacity still shows a click.  But - what css would I use to have a different background colour used when a radio button is clicked? I've tried using 
.answerGroup input[type="radio"]:checked
but this keeps the original grey colour

Comment: I didn't see the issue with the clicking  on the radio until now - that's going to be a problem

Comment: Updated the question with the code - I fixed the issue Nikhil pointed out, but still having some styling issues

Comment: You should implement this logic in the component answerGroup itself. You have to do two things. First update the `handleChange` function to update the state `answer.chosen`. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018261/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-props-onchange) . Second, Since `<button>` accepts a prop `style` where you can add css properties to it. Do something like `style={{ color: choosen ? 'blue' : 'grey' }}`. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I just realized that this is you assignment so you try adding conditional styles yourself I have already provides some hints to work on also you have to make `props.answers` as a state in the component even update the `answers` to have `id`. Get back here if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Still not getting this - and I think I've miscommunicated in some of my variable names.  I am going to re-edit the question (I think chosen has confused - so I'll make clear what that is )

Comment: Refactored to put in the correct place - so now AnswerGroup is gone - i's part of the parent component